# Is there a limit to iterating over arrays in Jade/Express?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express, pug

I'm trying to iterate over an nest of arrays in Jade. I seem to have hit a limit.

```
div().slidePreview
  ul
    each slide in slides
      div
        each section in slide
          li
            each image in section
              img(class= image.orientation, src='http://stevepainter.s3.amazonaws.com/images/thumbs/' + image.filename)
```

One less iteration and it works fine (i.e. each section in slides[0]). If I console.log(image) I get the full object. If I console.log(image.orientation) I get the orientation but in the browser I get:-

```
18| each image in section 19| -console.log(image.orientation) 20| img(class= image.orientation, src='http://stevepainter.s3.amazonaws.com/images/thumbs/' + image.filename) 21| Cannot read property 'orientation' of undefined> 18| each image in section 19| -console.log(image.orientation) 20| img(class= image.orientation, src='http://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.s3.amazonaws.com/images/thumbs/' + image.filename) 21| Cannot read property 'orientation' of undefined>
```

Please help this is killing me!!!!

Comment: Please use the right syntax for code. This is unreadable.

Comment: what happens if you replace it with a diferent type (simpler) nested element?  That would tell you whether it's depth or something specifically wrong with that nested element.

Comment: ksol This is correct syntax - it's Jade.

Comment: ksol was referring to the fact that you didn't use the right Markdown syntax for formatting your post so that your code would be shown the way you wrote it, rather than as a blob of unformatted text (e.g. all your indentation vanishes if you don't start each line with at least four spaces). Bergi was kind enough to edit your post and reformat it so that it's now readable.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. The array included an undefined element (even though I ran it through array.filter first to stop that). I just added !(image === "" || typeof image == "undefined" || image === null) to an if statement on the jade file and it worked.

Thanks for the comments.